# netlogo, ticks is slower if setting a variable

Tags: performance, variables, netlogo

**NORMAL TICKS SPEED:**

```
ask turtles with [seated? = 0] [
        fd speed
        if (pxcor > -5 and pxcor < 10) and (pycor > 5 and pycor < 10) [facexy (87 + random 4) (6 + random 4) fd speed]
        if (pxcor > 25 and pxcor < 28) and (pycor > 5 and pycor < 12) [
          let choice random 2
          fd speed
          if choice = 0 [leftbench]
          if choice = 1 [facexy 75 (6 + random 5)]
        ]
        if (pxcor > 73 and pxcor < 79) and (pycor > 5 and pycor < 15) [rightbench fd speed]
        if pcolor = brown and not any? other turtles-here
        [ move-to patch-here
          set seated? true
          set pcolor orange
          ]
      ]
```

**SLOW TICKS SPEED:**

```
ask turtles with [seated? = 0] [
        let gate patches with [(pxcor >= 88 and pxcor  <= 90) and (pycor >= 5)] 
        fd speed
        if (pxcor > -5 and pxcor < 10) and (pycor > 5 and pycor < 10) [face one-of gate fd speed]
        if (pxcor > 25 and pxcor < 28) and (pycor > 5 and pycor < 12) [
          let choice random 2
          fd speed
          if choice = 0 [leftbench]
          if choice = 1 [facexy 75 (6 + random 5)]
        ]
        if (pxcor > 73 and pxcor < 79) and (pycor > 5 and pycor < 15) [rightbench fd speed]
        if pcolor = brown and not any? other turtles-here
        [ move-to patch-here
          set seated? true
          set pcolor orange
          ]
      ]
```

the problem is, I want to make the speed normal every time I set a variable to make coding a lot easier and more organized.. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a chunk of code you want to use twice, put it in a procedure.

Then whenever you need that chunk of code, you don't have to repeat it using copy-and-paste; you just call the procedure.

If the procedure needs to be able to behave a little differently, depending on where it's being used, you might have the procedure take inputs, and then have it inspect those inputs to decide what to do.

See http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#procedures .

I hope this helps? I'm not entirely sure I'm addressing your question, but if I'm not, maybe you can clarify what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for this Seth Tisue, it really helped me before :) just replied now though